# Creating a vector

Tags: matrices, vectors

Create vector $$ such that $^x$, for a given vector $x$ in each part.

1) $^$  extracts (is equal to) the $7$th entry of the  $10$-vector $$

$a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]$

2) $^$  is the weighted average of a $3$-vector $$, assigning weights $0.3$ to the first component, $0.4$ to the second, and $0.3$ to the third.

$a = [0.3/3, 0.4/3, 0.3/3]$

3) $^$ (with $$ a $22$-vector) is the sum of $_$ for $$ a multiple of $4$, minus the sum of $_$ for $$ a multiple of $7$.

4) $^$ (with $$ an $11$-vector) is the average of the middle three entries of $$, i.e., entries $5$ to $7$.

I'm having trouble with 3 and 4.

Comment: I don't understand the context. Is $a$ in a $22$-dimensional vector space? What are the $x_i$?

Comment: @ElliotG I have edited it with examples for ease of clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2) Your answer here isn't correct: using the given weights already creates the desired weighted average, so dividing by $3$ on top of that is unnecessary and wrong.

3) Same logic as you used in the first problem. Here you want all elements whose index (position) is a multiple of $4$ to be taken with a coefficient of $1$ thus adding them together, and at the same time you want all elements whose index (position) is a multiple of $7$ to be taken with a coefficient of $-1$ thus adding subtracting all of them.

4) You need to take the average of the three entries: the $5$th, the $6$th, and the $7$th ones, so you here (unlike in the second question) you need to multiply each of them by $1/3$, while you "kill off" all the other entries with zeroes like you did (correctly!) in the first problem.

Comment: So would 4 be $([0,0,0,0,1/11*(1/3),1/11*(1/3),1/11*(1/3),0,0,0,0])$ and 2 be just [0.3,0.4,0.3]

Comment: and 3 would be [0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,1,-1,0]

Comment: For 2): yes. For 3): you're missing several more $1$s and one more $-1$. Make a list of all multiples of $4$ up to $22$, and make a list of all multiples of $7$ up to $22$. For 4): why $1/11$? How many numbers are you averaging?

Comment: Sorry, I reedited

I mean 3 is  [0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,1,-1,0] and for 4, if averaging only 3 numbers, would the answer just be all 0s except entries 5,6,7 are 1 or would it be all 0's except for entries 5,6,7 being 1/3 ?

Comment: @i9-9980XE: Well, if you need to average three numbers, say $a$, $b$, and $c$, then their average is $\frac{a+b+c}{3}=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{3}$, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but the individual values are unknown, would it be [0,0,0,0,1/3,1/3,1/3,0,0,0,0] or [0,0,0,0,3*(1/3),3*(1/3),3*(1/3),0,0,0,0], as 3 values are only counted. Thus being 1 when averaging them all.

Comment: @i9-9980XE: If you use $3\cdot(1/3)=1$ in those places in the vector $\mathbf{a}$, you will end up adding the corresponding three entries of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ instead of averaging them.